# Windows 10 Upgrade: Not enough disk space?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, dell-venue

I'm trying to upgrade a Dell Venue tablet from Windows 8.1 (which came pre-installed) to Windows 10. I downloaded the Microsoft Media Creation Tool (or whatever it's called) to immediately start the upgrade process. At first it told me that everything checked out; here is an actual screenshot from that tool (below) indicating that I met the requirements for CPU, Memory, and Disk space.

[image: prerequisites]

It then says it will automatically start the Windows 10 download in 9 seconds. Once it does, however, instead of actually downloading anything it just gives me the following error message: "Not enough disk space, please run Disk Cleanup and try again."

[image: error]

I find it really frustrating that the tool, one moment, tells me I have enough disk space, and then in the next moment tells me I don't. I did run the Disk Cleanup tool, which was only able to clean a whopping 10 MB, because I had already done a factory reset of the tablet (meaning it didn't have *anything* on it). As you can see, I have 16.7 of 22.9 GB free after the factory reset.  Supposedly it only needs 16 (which I have), so I'm confused why it's not letting me upgrade.

[image: space]

Unfortunately as you might have guessed it is literally impossible to free up any more space than the 16.7 GB listed, since that is what is available fresh after a factory reset. Any advice on how to proceed? How can I get Windows 10 on this machine?

Comment: 16GB isn't enough to use the media creation tool, you can use the tool to create a bootable flash drive, but the upgrade process requires more the. 16GB.  You can also format the device and install Windows 10 allowing it to detect the Windows 8.x key

Comment: use USB flash drives to store the WIn10 data: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Lots-of-Windows-10-Stick-PCs-PST-tips-Zombie-Libraries-and-more#time=2m00s

Comment: have you tried the USb thumb drives to use 1 of it as temporary drive?